# log4net File Created date never changes for RollingFileAppender

Tags: c#, log4net

When using the log4net RollingFileAppender I have observed that when a roll-over at midnight occurs, the "Date Created" of the new log file is fixed to the day the original file was created. The old log file is renamed correctly to e.g. Application-20230808.log as I want.

[image]

Is this a bug and have anyone else observed this?

Created a Windows service with log4net 2.0.15 and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore.
When creating normal files